# The file “Info.plist” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file

Tags: xcode, react-native, react-i18next

I'm getting this error message every time I try to build

```
: could not read data from '/Users/user/Desktop/development/mlife/node_modules/react-native-locale-detector/RNI18nTests/Info.plist': The file “Info.plist” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file.
```

I tried a lot of solutions but failed
- I tried to reinstall react-native-locale-detector
- tried to paste the path of info.plist
- tried to remove the project from the xcode and add it again

Comment: are you sure that 'react-native-locale-detector' is in your node_modules? if yes, delete node modules and run 'npm install' again

Comment: I tried but still getting the same error

Comment: Are you 100% positive the file does not exist?

Comment: yes .. also `RNI18nTests` folder not exist